# windows azure wcf problems using an asmx file with logic in an svc

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, asmx, svc

Currently in the company there is a service that is running in windows azure, I did some changes that needs to go to production but the service is not working properly when I run this in the Azure Emulator.

In the visual studio solution it looks something similar to this:

> Service1.svc.cs //<-- It has all the implemented methods
>   Service1.svc
>   Service1.asmx //<-- It uses the logic in Service1.svc.cs

My problem is that if I run this not using windows azure it works perfect, but if I run this from windows azure emulator it does not work properly, the result is opened in another window using a different port.

For example, if I'm calling a method on the following address:

```
http://127.0.0.1:81/Service1.asmx
```

When I execute the method it returns something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:82/Service1.asmx/CurrentVersion
```

I read that for previous versions a problem existed with WCF and the load balancers, but in this case I am using .NET 4.0 and Azure 1.7.

In the web.config I also added some configuration which other forums says that it would solve the problems with the balancers.

```xml
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <!-- Test from microsoft -->
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
            <defaultPorts>
              <add scheme="http" port="81" />
              <add scheme="https" port="444" />
            </defaultPorts>
          </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Does anyone know how should I tackle the problem?

Below is an example of my code:

```
 public class Service1 : IService1
 {
     public string CurrentVersion(string accountcode)
     {
         SiteServiceConfiguration sitecfg = GetSiteServiceConfiguration(accountcode);
         return sitecfg.CurrentVersion;
     }
 }

[ServiceContract]
[WebService(Name = "Service1")]
[WebServiceBinding(Name = "ServiceSoap1", ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1, EmitConformanceClaims = false)]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebMethod]
    string CurrentVersion(string accountcode);
}
```

Other info:

This webservice is called from an application written in .NET 1.1, while this is upgraded to a newer version I need to make the service to work.

Comment: I got the answer on this forum http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/windowsazuremanagement/thread/173ad7ef-190e-40f9-b8c0-6203398088fc